# How to track WHEN a model attribute changes using Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I need to find a way to track the specific moment in which a model attribute has changed from one state to another.

- For example, let's say I have a `List` model with an attribute called
  `voting_status`, which can be either `true` or `false`.
- That attribute can be changed by the owner of a list with the press
  of a button from `true` to `false`, so that other users can start voting on it.
- Once the first user votes, the `voting_status` changes back and the
  other users are not able to vote anymore, even though they did not get the chance to vote in the first place.
- So I would like to make an `if` statement that checks if a user voted between the moment the owner clicked the button and now by using another model I have called `Vote`, which tracks the user that voted and the item which was voted.
- The pseudo-code would look something like this:

  `vote = Vote.find_by(user_id: 4)
  list = List.find(5)
  if vote.created_at is_between  list.voting_status_changed?(from: true, to: false).when..DateTime.now
  user cannot vote
  else
  user can vote
  end`
- Unfortunately, I did not find any `when` method or something similar that can return the date in which the owner clicked that button, thus updating the attribute.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Update a timestamp when it changes? Create an audit log with the action and a timestamp? Use an existing audit log gem?

Comment: Audit Logs? Sounds interesting :) I never used one before so if you know a good place to get started, please let me know.

Comment: Actually, I was also thinking about creating another model that keeps track of each time the owner clicks the button.

Comment: CollectiveIdea's Audited, another gem which I found perfect for this type of situation https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited

Comment: Thanks RAJ. I'll have a look at that and try integrating it.

Comment: @RAJ... it appears that CollectiveIdea's Audited does now work for Rails 4. Do you happen to know any similar Gem?

Comment: @sebmih sorry I thought you are using rails 3. I have edited question to make it clear.. :) Also have added other gems to my answer.. have a look

Comment: @sebmih As a good learner and contributor, if you found any answer useful, you should upvote for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use one of the following gems to keep track of changes.

[Espinita](https://github.com/continuum/espinita)

[Papertrail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail)

[Miks' Audited](https://github.com/miks/audited/tree/rails4)

All the above mentioned gems will work for you

**EDIT:** I have not used but you can give a try to [Public Activity](https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity) Gem too.

Comment: `Espinita` did the job! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There is Auditable Gem, that would do the trick for you. Though there are lots of others that have similar functuinality, see related section https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/auditable

Comment: Thanks but `Auditable` does not work in Rails 4 due to some dependencies related to `ActiveRecord`.